# php making an assoc array in a for loop doesn't set the key

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

so i'm trying to make a small card game as an exercise. I'm trying to make an associative array that contains the name of the card as a key and the card value as the value.

when i check the key and value separate they are correct but if i print_r the array i make it shows something like: array([0] => harten1 [1] => harten2   etc.

can someone explain to me why this is happening and how i can fix this?
Many thanks in advance!

```
function MaakNieuweStapel() {
$soorten = array("harten", "ruiten", "klaveren", "schoppen");
$values = array("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9", "10", "boer", "dame", "heer");

//add all combinations
for ($i = 0; $i < count($soorten); $i++) {
    for ($j = 0; $j < count($values); $j++) {
        //value assignment
        $key = $soorten[$i] . $values[$j];
        $value = $j + 1;           
        $trekstapel[$key] = $value;
    }
}

shuffle($trekstapel);
//print for checking
print_r($trekstapel);
return $trekstapel;
```

}

Comment: If you put the `print_r($trekstapel);` before the `shuffle()` you can see the keys are there.

Comment: as you said the shuffle was indeed the problem. On the other post I found this to be the solution: chang shuffle() with uksort($array, function() { return rand() > getrandmax() / 2 });